# Difference between Eclipse preference names

Tags: eclipse

I couldn't find any documentation around the difference between two properties I found in Eclipse preference files.

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/sp_cleanup.remove_trailing_whitespaces=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/sp_cleanup.remove_trailing_whitespaces_all=true
```

They both remove trailing whitespaces. That part is clear. But is there a reason to set both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is whether or not empty lines are included when removing trailing whitespace. If `sp_cleanup.remove_trailing_whitespaces_all` is `true`, all lines have whitespace trimmed; if `false`, empty lines are ignored.

This is controlled by this part of the Save Actions configuration UI:

[image]